# How to check effective routes in Azure VMSS?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS deployed in a subnet inside VNet. I want to check all the effective routes available on this VMSS for network troubleshooting, but I cannot find any options to view it.

For VMs, one can easily see the Effective Routes on the Network Interface's page in Azure Portal.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using PowerShell and the [Get-AzEffectiveRouteTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azeffectiveroutetable?view=azps-9.7.1) cmdlet

```
$ResourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroup"
$VMMSNicName = "YourVMSSNetworkInterfaceNICName"

$VMSSNic = Get-AzNetworkInterface `
    -ResourceGroupName $rgname `
    | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$vmmsnicname*"} | Select-Object -First 1 
# I am making the assumption that the first one will be the one of the VMSS NICS.

Get-AzEffectiveRouteTable `
    -NetworkInterfaceName $VMSSNic.name `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName | ft -AutoSize
```

kind regards

Alistair

Comment: your above solution only works for VMs and not VM ScaleSets.